# How does AdoQuery handle blobs?

Tags: delphi, memory, delphi-2010, ado

I am testing some databases components such as `SDAC` and others and I found out something interesting:

When I execute a query with `TADOQuery` and this query has a lot of blob fields and I get all rows (`fetchall`) the memory of my application gets close to 1.8GB and everything works fine.

Using other components, the same query executed on the same database trows an `Out of Memory` exception because it exceeds 1.8GB of memory usage.

I know I should not return all those rows, i should use pagination and blablabla. But i am curious how can ADO manage to get all rows and other components cant.

I think that ADO is compressing the blobs in memory, but this is only a guess.

Does anyone knows why memory usage in ADO is so good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say about SDAC, but will say about [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) TADQuery:

- if exclude fiBlobs from FetchOptions.[Items](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/uADStanOption_TADFetchOptions_Items.html), then AnyDAC will not fetch BLOB values immediately. But will defer fetching until the application will really need a BLOB value;
- setting FormatOptions.[InlineDataSize](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/uADStanOption_TADFormatOptions_InlineDataSize.html) to more small value, will reduce memory usage on fetching large result set with multiple character fields;
- specifying FormatOptions.[MapRules](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/uADStanOption_TADFormatOptions_MapRules.html), application may choose more compact data type representation.

Also there are few other techniques, allowing to reduce memory usage when fetching large result sets. To use them properly a developer should know what kind of data will be returned. The price of some options usage may be a slightly reduced fetch performance.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer my question. I know a lot about your components, in specially sdac, but i am interested in how TADOQuery works internally.